# Connection Authentication Failure Occured

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, derby

I am trying to load the derby sample database on my machine through NetBeans and populate a table.  Unfortunately I am getting an error about userid or password being invalid.  This is the default derpy sample database and i an unable to find out where a username and password could be located.

The index file:

```
<%@page import="webstoreUtils.*,java.sql.*,org.apache.derby.jdbc.*"%>
<%@ include file="admin/connection.jsp" %> 
<%ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from APP.PRODUCT"); %>
<%= WebstoreUtils.getHeader("Welcome to Comp-orium!") %>
<h2>Welcome to Comp-orium</h2> 
<h4>Daily Steal</h4> 
<%= WebstoreUtils.getNavigation() %> 
<p>Click a Title to view more information</p> 
<%= WebstoreUtils.getTable(rs,0,true,2,1,"details.jsp") %> 
<%= WebstoreUtils.getFooter() %> 
<%@ include file="admin/close.jsp" %>
```

The Connection file

```
<%
String dbURI = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
DriverManager.registerDriver(new ClientDriver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURI);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
%>
```

Webstore Utils is a class that simply returns html script to the page.

Comment: you would normally pass username/password to the getConnection method.

Comment: Do not use java inside jsp. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202